# Rough estimation of centroid with dft

Tags: c++, opencv, fft, dft, fourier-descriptors

I would like the coordinates for the centroid and I have already calculated the DFT (for a different purpose). I've seen some slides that hint on the possibility to get a rough estimation of the centroid by looking at the first values of the matrix.
The code is based on: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

```
cv::dft(complexI, complexI);
// compute the magnitude and switch to logarithmic scale
// => log(1 + sqrt(Re(DFT(I))^2 + Im(DFT(I))^2))
cv::split(complexI, planes); // planes[0] = Re(DFT(I), planes[1] = Im(DFT(I))
double x = (double)planes[0].at<int>(0,0)/INT_MAX;
double y = ABS(((double)planes[1].at<int>(0,0)/INT_MAX));
```

But every time the y value becomes 0. The x value seem correct though. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what your inputs, outputs, and expeceted outputs are.  If you spelled that out it might help.

Aside: in C++, you can use C++ style casting instead of C style casting.  E.g. double myDouble = static_cast<double>(myInteger);
I think that would help with the readability.

Comment: Are you referring to the "Spectral Centroid":http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_centroid?

Comment: planes[0].at<int> should be planes[0].at<float> ( or double. please check planes[0].type() )

Comment: @adi-shavit Geometrical Centroid - http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/fourier_analysis.pdf

Comment: @berak you mean it will not convert the value? Even so 0.0f == 0 in memory (the sign, exponent and mantissa are all zeros). The y value should be somewhere around 0.5 instead of 0.0 . The x value is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is more commonly done using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#moments).